# When I try to share my notes from Apple Books, the share menu is empty

Tags: ios, books

[image]

This is what I get. 
Perhaps it's caused by the latest update? I am on iPhone 6, iOS 12. And my iCloud sync for Books is disabled.

Comment: When you tap on the 'More' button, do you see the different ways you can share the notes?  I can share my notes without a problem (iOS 12) so it's not a bug in iOS.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. I am on 12.1.2